# Create different instance of buttons in view controller for tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a `UITableView` that has cells where a `UIViewController` opens up when you click on one. I have a vote button on the `UIViewController` that I want to toggle between "yes" and "no" each time the user clicks on it. However when I click a table cell, then the vote button, then back to `UITableView` and click on that same cell again it defaults back to "yes". How would i keep it from reverting back to "yes" as well as having each cell open up a different instance of the button being either "yes" or "no"?

Comment: Consider including an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you push the view controller, or in prepareForSegue, set the initial value for the vote to be the value in the selected cell. Assuming I understood the question to be that you want the voting controller to reflect the current value in the cell.

In `viewWillAppear` of your voting controller, set the voting button/view to the value you set on push.

This should mean that the controller comes up with the same value the cell had last time.